# In Windows 10, can I shuffle a different wallpaper on each of four displays?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I'm running Windows 10 and have two ATI Radeon HD 5750 video cards outputting to four monitors. I like to have my wallpapers shuffle through my favorite pictures. Is there a way to have each monitor show a different picture? As it is, three monitors show one picture and the fourth shows another. More specifically, if my monitors are 1 through 4 left to right, I'll get one picture on #1 and a different picture on #2-4. When it shuffles, #2 stays the same and #1, #3, and #4 show a new picture. On the next shuffle, #1 stays the same and #2-4 change. Rinse and repeat.

How can I get each monitor to show its own wallpaper and then have them shuffle? I have tried opening up the legacy wallpaper page through the run command using `control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper`, but selecting a single image and then right-clicking only gives me the options of "Set for all monitors," "Set for monitor 1," or "Set for monitor 4."

Comment: It should be possible, but somehow your windows does not detect all 4 monitors. Its likely that your AMD card groups 3 monitors as 1 monitor and windows treats it as 1. You should look into your ATI control Center to set this up properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, Catalyst Control Center shows all four displays ungrouped. I could not find any options allowing for separate control of wallpaper backgrounds.